# How to apply wallpaper from assets using built-in cropper?

Tags: java, android

I want to apply a wallpaper from assets using the default cropper (shown below):

[image: Default cropper]

This is usually done by using the `WallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(ContentUri uri);`

However, I can't figure out how the use the images *from the assets* to do this. The problem is that this method requires Content URI, and all I have from the assets is the "usual" URI: `file:///android_asset/...`

How can I do this? Is there a workaround to this method?